# jquery set focus on first textbox on pageload

Tags: jquery

i've tried doing this to set focus on pageload but it's not focusing

```
$('#profileForm :input[type=text]:first').focus();
```

how can i set forucs on the first control in #profileForm

update:

```
<div id="profileForm" runat="server" visible="true">
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('input[type=text], select, textarea').focus(function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('form-blur');
                        $(this).addClass('form-focus');
                    })

                    $('input[type=text], select, textarea').blur(function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('form-focus');
                        $(this).addClass('form-blur');
                    });
                    $('#profileForm input[type=text]').first().focus();
                });
            </script>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="form-label" style="white-space:nowrap">First Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td rowspan="8" style="width:100%; padding-left:10px" valign="top">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSummary" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Width="99%" /><br />
                        Summary            
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
       </div>
```

Comment: `input` isn't a pseudo-class--just delete the leading colon and you should be fine: $('#profileForm input[type=text]').first().focus();

Comment: its focusing for me http://jsfiddle.net/BbSLy/1/

Comment: Did you put it inside $(document).ready(){}?

Comment: ok, its working only in chrome.

Comment: @rjz - The [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) is valid, though using it together with `[type=text]` is not something I'd recommend - dropping the colon as you suggest is going to be more efficient.

Comment: the jsFiddle works i don't understand why its not working for me on my side same code aswell

Comment: Can you post more of your HTML? Your selector might be wrong or something, but without more context we can't help you.

Comment: I've updated my code. I have no other controls that have focus()

Comment: It works if I use $('form input[type=text]').first().focus();

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
 $('[id*=profileForm]').find('input:first').focus();
```

or another option

```
 $('[id*=profileForm]').find('input[type=text]:visible:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below selector for `input type=text`

```
$("#profileForm input:textarea:visible:first").focus();
```

For text area

```
$("#profileForm textarea:visible:first").focus();
```